# Mapbox script to html

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mapbox

I found this code on mapbox page. I need those coordinates to pass into html form. What is the best way to do this. I have tried using getdocumentbyId but for some reason I have more errors in that, and it doesn't work at all.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>
          
    <div id="map"></div>
    <pre id="coordinates" class="coordinates"></pre>
    
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my.tkn';
        var coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates');
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [18.38 , 43.848],
            zoom: 15
        });
    
        var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
            draggable: true
        })
            .setLngLat([18.38 , 43.848])
            .addTo(map);
    
        function onDragEnd() {
            var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
            coordinates.style.display = 'block';
            coordinates.innerHTML =
                'Longitude: ' + lngLat.lng + '<br />Latitude: ' + lngLat.lat;
        
    
        }
    
        
        marker.on('dragend', onDragEnd);
    </script>
    
    
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="hvalue" name="hvalue">
    <input type="text" id="wvalue" name="wvalue">

</form>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understood correct this is what you want to get:

-i relocate the script under the form.
-i added `getElementById().value =`

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
  
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
    <link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    </head>
    <body>
          
    <div id="map"></div>
    <pre id="coordinates" class="coordinates"></pre>
      
    
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="hvalue" name="hvalue">
    <input type="text" id="wvalue" name="wvalue">

</form>
    

<script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my.tkn';
        var coordinates = document.getElementById('coordinates');
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [18.38 , 43.848],
            zoom: 15
        });
    
        var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({
            draggable: true
        })
            .setLngLat([18.38 , 43.848])
            .addTo(map);
    
        function onDragEnd() {
            var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
            coordinates.style.display = 'block';
            coordinates.innerHTML =
                'Longitude: ' + lngLat.lng + '<br />Latitude: ' + lngLat.lat;
            
            //im not sure which input needs to get which value, you can change if needed
            document.getElementById('hvalue').value = lngLat.lng
            document.getElementById('wvalue').value = lngLat.lat
        }
    
        
        marker.on('dragend', onDragEnd);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I wanted to values from script (of coordinates )to pass to form, so I could send them to backend and at the end to db.

Comment: Im not sure i understand, but put this code and see that the input get the coordinates, then you need to post the form to the backend and save it in the db. how to post and store it is a different question.